# A (very naive) question about Homotopy Type Theory

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lo.logic, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

In homotopy type theory, homotopy types can be viewed as logical types and it is possible to prove some theorems about them without using any underlying space (no simplicial set, no topological space). It is a kind of synthetic algebraic topology. Is it just a coincidence that the word "type" may have these two meanings ? What I mean is: what had in mind the one who invented this terminology of "homotopy types" ? And do we even know where that terminology of "homotopy types" comes from. I guess that the answer will be that it is a coincidence but since it is written nowhere in the book, I ask the question in order to be sure.

Comment: Il faut demander au type qui a inventé le terme.

Comment: It's a coincidence, but a very fortunate one (for a change). When people started saying "homotopy type" X they meant "the type of X" as in "what kind of space is X". When people said "type" X in logic, they meant the type of its terms, as in "what kind of thing is an $x \in X$ ". In a naive sense, these two usages of "type" are not actually the same. Luckily, as one digs deeper, it turns out by lucky coincidence that at the bottom of it indeed this is the same notion of "type" in both cases. I think its one of those trivialities that deserve to be regarded as "deep".

Comment: @Jonathan Chiche: oui en somme, il nous faut faire la rencontre du troisième type.

Comment: It seems that HoTT is fashionable enough that the hawks have not descended on this question and branded it as "soft" and "not mathematical".

Comment: I am inclined to think that this is not a mere coincidence. Rather, that this is some sort of reflection of the fact that mathematicians tend to think in predicable ways.

Comment: @BabyDragon When you say "think in predic(t)able ways", do you mean in the sense that we are able to communicate meaningfully with each other without spelling everything out completely, or in the sense that we don't break out of the box much?

Comment: @S.Carnahan I mean that we do not get too far away from the box for physical and psychological reasons (Oddly the way we speak about boxes is squarely in the box). I should note that this idea is not completely fleshed out.

Comment: This is an additional comment to my post. What is remarkable is not that there is a homotopy theory of types: after all, there are a lot of homotopy theories of many kinds of objects. What is remarkable is that the homotopy theory of logical types behaves exactly like "standard" homotopy types. And also, there are other coincidences in mathematics which are indeed not very fortunate. Some adjectives like "regular" or "normal" are semantically overloaded.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Maybe I should repost my comment above as a genuine answer:

It's a coincidence, but a very fortunate one (for a change).

- When people started saying "[homotopy type](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy%20type)" $X$ they meant "the type of $X$" as in "what kind of space is X?".
- When people said "[type](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/type)" $X$ in logic ([type theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/type%20theory)), they meant the type of its [terms](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/term), as in "what kind of thing is an $x \in X$?".

In a naive sense, these two usages of "type" are not actually the same. Remarkably, as one digs deeper and understands that [intensional type theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/intensional%20type%20theory) is essentially [homtopy type theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy%20type%20theory), it turns out by lucky coincidence that at the bottom of it indeed this is the same notion of "type" in both cases.

I think its one of those trivialities that deserve to be regarded as "deep".

Comment: The motivation of this question was the reading of chapter 8 of the book. It is the first (soft and non-mathematical) question which came to mind.

Answer (score 9):

There seem to be at least two distinct traditions in mathematics for the use of 'type'.

The 'Homotopy types' of algebraic topology seem to have been defined in analogy to 'order types'.  Two ordered sets have the same order type when they are isomorphic.  Cantor defined the ordinal numbers to be the order types of well-ordered sets.  I have not checked whether he used the German equivalent of the word 'type'.

The 'intensional types' of HoTT originate with Bertrand Russell's approach to resolving his paradox by requiring each mathematical object to be of some type, with constraints on which objects are allowed to belong to any given type. Any formal quantifier could only be a quantifier over some type. This was in contrast to Frege who allowed all of his objects to belong to a single realm which could be quantified over.

No doubt both traditions have a source in everyday usage; e.g. from the free dictionary

Type: A number of people or things having in common traits or characteristics that distinguish them as a group or class.